# iOS application token auth best practices

Tags: api, ios, authentication

I am looking into building an iOS application and using an internally built API to access data. My API has some authentication endpoints that takes in a username and password and, if the login is successful, it spits out a JWT.

My question is, what are best practices for iOS logins such as this? I've been doing some research and have not been able to find anything that answers this particular question.

Answer (score 1):

The JWT token should remain in memory (if each time you use your app you get a new one). Assuming the session persists between app launches, then you need to store it, the correct place for tokens / credentials is the KeyChain.